# Why Doesn't my steam browser auto log me in on the steam store

Tags: steam

Basically what happened is I launch steam then I click store and it doesn't load steam doesn't auto log me on, how do I fix this?

Comment: same problem happens to me, haven't found a solution yet, will update as soon as I find one. For my case, re-logging in and manually logging both didn't work for some reason.

Comment: Unfortunately, it sounds like something only Steam support could help you with. My only guess is that the Steam broswer doesn't store your login credentials (most likely in a browser cookie) for some reason. But I don't know what kind of browser Steam client uses, so I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Usually, this is just a temporary problem.  Incidentally, @DJPirtu, Steam uses the Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF).

Comment: "...and it doesn't load steam doesn't auto log me on...". If I knew what you meant by that, I'd edit the question. Unfortunately thats not the case.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue on my computer its from some program not allowing that info to be saved permently...

if you exit steam and go to the Run command in your start menu and put "steam://flushconfig" without quotes and let it run choosing ok for any thing it pops up with reset the steam config and make sure nothing is wrong with the program it will not mess with any games installed just the steam program itself.. then reboot and try again... worked for me ... you will also need to go to the C:\Users(username)\AppData\Local\Steam whlie steam is shutdown and delete the htmlcache folder...